# Synchronizing access to an inner object's methods?

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following:

```
public class Foo {
    private ReadingList mReadingList = new ReadingList();

    public ReadingList getReadingList() {
        synchronized (mReadingList) {
            return mReadingList;
        }
    }
}
```

If I try modifying the ReadingList object in two threads, the synchronization above won't help me, right?:

```
// Thread 1
foo1.getReadingList().setName("aaa");

// Thread 2
foo2.getReadingList().setName("bbb");
```

do I have to wrap each method I want synchronized like so:

```
public class Foo {
    private ReadingList mReadingList = new ReadingList();

    public synchronized void setReadingListName(String name) {
        mReadingList.setName(name);
    }

    public synchronized void setReadingListAuthor(String author) {
        mReadingList.setAuthor(author);
    }

    ...
```

and so on for each method of ReadingList I want exposed and synched? I'd end up just writing wrapper methods for each method of ReadingList.

Thanks

Comment: What is ReadingList? If it is thread safe you don't need synchronization at all (since the operations you do are all atomic from the Foo class perspective) - just make it final?

Comment: In the example, are 'name' and 'author' intended to be properties of the list itself and not properties of list members (say, of a list of Book objects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.  You have access to the ReadingList source

If you have access to the ReadingList object, add `synchronized` to all of the methods of ReadingList if you desire synchronized access to all of the fields or a certain group of setters if you only wish to interleave access to certain fields.

#### 2.  You do not have access to ReadingList

You would have to write something like:

```
public class Foo {
    private ReadingList mReadingList = new ReadingList();

    public void setReadingListName(String name) {
        synchronized(mReadingList) {
           mReadingList.setName(name);
        }
    }

    public void setReadingListAuthor(String author) {
        synchronized(mReadingList) {
           mReadingList.setAuthor(author);
        }
    }

    ...
```

#### 3.  Use a general purpose lock object

Depending on the nature of Foo and how general-purpose this whole thing is, you may find that only a certain class or classes present the threading issue in ReadingList.

In such a class you could use a general purpose lock object:

```
public class Bar {
   Object readingListLock = new Object();

   public void someMethodThatModifiesReading() {
      synchronized(readingListLock) {
          foo.getReadingList().setName("1");
      }
   }

   public void someOtherMethodThatModifiesReading() {
      synchronized(readingListLock) {
          foo.getReadingList().setName("2");
      }
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Of course (3) doesn't make Foo or ReadingList any more thread safe in general, but in an internal API you may not care.

Answer (score 1):

A quick (and not so efficient solution) is to synchronize all methods of `ReadingList` in `ReadingList`'s implementation.

Look for Reader-Writer lock for a more efficient way to synchronize access: it allows multiple reads and single write at a time.

Your first solution only makes sure one thread gets the `ReadingList` at a time, and nothing else - many threads can read and modify the `ReadingList` concurrently.

Comment: With Reader-Writer lock, just be careful that high numbers of current reads don't cause write-starvation.

Comment: @jkschneider: Only one of the synchronized methods can be called at any time: "First, it is not possible for **two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave**. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object."